# Are some people just unable to code?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, self-improvement

So for the past year or so, I've been trying to self-teach myself programming. The problem is, every time I start to try and teach myself (like on Codecademy and such) I start off great and then proceed to get lost. I've tried a few different langs (Python, Java, C) and all end with the same result of me struggling to remember / implement the lower level concepts and then giving up.

So I'm starting to think that either a) I'm going about this the wrong way or b) maybe some people just can't code (and I'm one of them). I'm hoping it is the former rather than the latter, but I would love some of your advice and maybe some tips on how I can better prepare myself.

Thanks

Comment: Not everyone learns the same way.  Try a different approach.  Rather than 'learning to code' in the abstract by following tutorials and lesson plans, set out to actually make something.  Many people learn better via practical application.

Comment: The same question could be asked about any other skill. E.g.: Are some people just unable to play the piano? Well, yes.

Comment: According to [this blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/), not even people who call themselve programmers can always program.

Comment: You can always be an 'architect' or 'scrum master'

Answer (score 6):

Programming is a skill like any other. Among other things, that means that learning it by following the outline of sites like codeacademy is probably unrealistic for some (most) people.

That isn't to say that those people can't learn, rather that those sites by nature of their design tend to imply that if you've solved problem X you're proficient and comfortable enough to solve problem X+1. That isn't necessarily true, most people need to practice. It's why schools assign homework and spend more than one lesson on most topics. As a concrete example, I would be truly amazed if someone was truly comfortable with pointers having solved a single lesson on them from one of those sites.

In terms of practical advice, that means it's probably worth your while to practice. If the sites you're using don't have additional problems of similar difficulty with similar subject material, try making your own. Think about what you might be able to do with what you know, or with what you know and maybe a little more. Then do it.

Eventually you'll cross the line between 'I passed the lesson on loops' and 'I'm really very comfortable with loops.' Then try revisiting the site to progress because you no longer have to spend brainpower wrangling your loops and you can focus on the new material.

Comment: Yeah, I like this answer. However I would like to add that, as someone who taught themselves programming basically from scratch, it also depends on _which language_ you start with. For example, I started with a keen interest in doing things with computers, and picked up Batch file scripting. Then on to Visual Basic .NET (ugh), then to HTML/CSS/JS, then a bit of Java, then C++... So I'd say start with the basics - that's just my opinion though :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this without veering off into general philosophy.  What does it mean to not be able to learn something?  Is it always just a matter of there being some missing link that all your teachers have taken for granted, or are some people genuinely incapable of learning certain things?

How to teach programming is a major topic of interest in computer science.  Countless papers have been written about it.  Here's [a random one](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV52Simon2.pdf) that I found.  But there doesn't even seem to be wide consensus about whether programming is harder to teach or learn than other subjects.  Conventional wisdom says it is, but the few studies that have been done say that the dropout rate is about the same as in other majors.

This is pure opinion, but my view is that the way programming is taught is universally pretty awful.  Literally every "teach yourself programming" book I've ever seen introduces key topics in a way (and in an order) that's very different from how I, as a professional, think they should be taught.  Universities in particular have failed miserably, and even the students who do well in their courses tend to be marginal programmers.  The Venn diagram of things new graduates know and things I wish my co-workers knew barely overlaps.  [A few have opined](http://www.wsj.com/articles/computer-programming-is-a-trade-lets-act-like-it-1407109947) that programming should be taught as a trade skill.  I agree.  Unfortunately, that's a relatively new idea, and there aren't many educational resources that are structured that way.  As more books and courses become available, maybe you will find more success.

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to learn given the outset of 'I want to learn to code'. However if you can give yourself a small project, like a basic calculator, you'll then have some context to learn the aspects of the language you have chosen. Then just think of new features to add which will give you reason to explore more of the toolbox.

To begin with, try and stick to the same language, and then as you become more comfortable with your first language, you'll realise many of the similarities with other languages, and that many of the differences are simply syntax.

More so, when you end up delving into lower level terms, which may have documentation that's difficult for a learner to understand, be afraid not. Take your time, and make good use of the search functions on here and stack overflow, as many concepts and features have been described in a way which is easier to understand.

Good luck, if you've got a true desire to code. You'll get there!

Answer (score -1):

As long as you have interest on coding, you can do it. Not everyone remembers the syntax. It's all by practice and hands-on. You can definitely give it a try and i am sure you will not feel for it later.